# What's the meaning of "taken to" in the following the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Exception **has been taken** to Gobbin's humour.

I am not able to understand "taken to" in particular.
Please, help me..

Answer (score 1):

According to the Collins Dictionary

**[take exception to something](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles/take-exception-to-something)**

> If you **take exception to something**, you feel offended or annoyed by it, usually with the result that you complain about it.
>   *He also took exception to having been spied on.
>
>   And the problem is that they take exception to any kind of noise whatsoever.*

Your phrase is using the passive voice: **exception** has become the subject.

> Exception **has been taken** to Gobbin's humour.

Active

> They **has taken exception** to Gobbin's humour.
>
> They have felt offended by Gobbin's humour and have complained about it.

Who are exactly **they** is explained probably in the rest of the text.